# Can't divide a div equally into 6 parts

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have some code here that splits a div into equally into six.

On desktop browsers this seems to work ok. On the safrai/ chrome on iOS, it doesn't.

You can view it here

http://jsfiddle.net/LZxxB/31/

On my desktop browsers, the height of each div is 50px and fills the container.
On mobile browsers, the height for each div is 49px and leaves a space at the bottom of the wrapper (you can see this as a red line on the fiddle above.

Any ideas why?

```
<div class="fretboardWrapper">
    <div class="strings">
        <div class="string" id="one"></div>
        <div class="string" id="two"></div>
        <div class="string" id="three"></div>
        <div class="string" id="four"></div>
        <div class="string" id="five"></div>
        <div class="string" id="six"></div>
    </div>
</div>

body{
    color:white;
}

#one, #three, #five {
    background:blue;
}
#two, #four, #six {
    background:green;
}
.strings {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.string {
    z-index:2;
    height:16.666%;
}
.fretboardWrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
}

<script>
$('#one').text($('#one').height());
$('#two').text($('#two').height());
$('#three').text($('#three').height());
$('#four').text($('#four').height());
$('#five').text($('#five').height());
$('#six').text($('#six').height());
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Interestingly, dividing into 5 works ok http://jsfiddle.net/LZxxB/33/

Is there a decimal place limit when using percentages in safrai mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a desktop browser and it's setting `49px`, not `50px` as you mentioned.

Simply changing `height` to `height:16.999%;` (`50px` each) solved the issue for me?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/LZxxB/35/)

*Updte: I tested in different browsers, Chrome is setting `50px`, Safari is setting `49px`. this much be the difference in rounding algorithm between the browsers. Simply setting height just above 50px (for eg. 16.69%)  should probably work cross browser..*

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/LZxxB/39/) is working fine for me on both chrome and safari..

Comment: The browser is setting the 49 percent. I  told the browser to set to 16.666% of the container height of 300px. You'll see that on the desktop the height of each div gets set to 50 but on mobile, it is 49. There must be some rounding going on.

Comment: @totalitarian Yes, the term `desktop browser` you used got me confused, because i was using safari on desktop and it was showing only 49px. This is the difference in rounding algo, setting height just above `50px` (e.g: `16.777%`) will make sure it works cross browser..

Answer (score -1):

Please update this

```
.string {
    z-index:2;
    height:17%;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Now on the desktop the divs are too big. Ie, 51px rather than 50px